# Word 2007: "Sentence case" behaviour when open a new document (without selecting before)

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

How can I write sentences so that the capitalized appear automatically at the beginning of sentence?

I know that by selecting the text and going to "Font" and then selecting "Tipo oración" ("Sentence case") from the `Aa` menu works. But how to display automatically without selecting text before? I mean, every time I open a Word document.

It was working like that before, but I don't know what I changed or touched.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be asking about auto-correct:
you type “it was working before.”
and it automagically changes into “It was working before.”

1. Click on “File” (left-most tab) in the ribbon.
2. Click on “Options”.
3. In the “Word Options” window, click on “Proofing”.
4. The right-side panel of the “Word Options” window
   says something like “Change how Word corrects and formats your text.” 
   Click on “AutoCorrect Options…”.
5. Enable “Capitalize first letter of sentences”.
6. Click on “OK” and “OK”.

[image: File]     [image: Options]
            [image: Proofing]
[image: AutoCorrect Options]

[image: ...]

You can also select text, or simply click on a word, and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>.
That will cycle the word or selected text through `lower case`, `Title Case (Initial Capitals)`, and `ALL CAPS`.